# How to hide stripe javascripts on webpage

Tags: javascript, php, payment-gateway, stripe-payments

How do I hide stripe js files being shown in the view-source ? I want to hide the name of the payment system company I am using from the competitors.

The stripe js files and javascripts are showing up on my checkout webpage.

```
<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>

var stripe = Stripe('pk_test_TYooMQauvdEDq54NiTphI7jx');

var elements = stripe.elements();
```

I was thinking to use their php api, will that do the job ? Any solution or method is appreciated.

Comment: You cannot hide client-side code other than using code obscuring mechanisms but anybody interested can simply check the browser's network tab and will see all domains that the website is communicating with.

Comment: you might want to redirect your users to `Stripe` dashboard for payments and using webhooks update your backend

Comment: Chris G, what about using stripe php apis ?

Comment: Sheelpriy, my point here is to hide stripe payment system from the clients. Redirecting users to stripe dashboard won't work

Comment: You cannot and you should not, I'm pretty sure stripe terms of service forbid you to do so and that you should actually include their name in your privacy policy since your are giving your client data to them, anyways it's not like hiding some source names is gonna do any good regarding competitors, anybody will still be able to trace it back or guess what it is if they wanted because of multiple reasons and stripe is quite a popular platform

Answer (score 0):

it is not possible to hide client side code, and it is not a big deal if users find out about the payment system you are using, as for stripe "security is their concern not yours".

but one important thing is that you have to validate everything in the backend part of your app. that is your concern.